# Have titlerule not overlap wrapfigure

Tags: sectioning, wrapfigure

I have defined my sectioning as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor,wrapfig,lipsum}
\definecolor{titelkleur}{HTML}{92D851}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{28}{32}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedright}%\underline
 {}
 {-0.5cm}
 {\textcolor{titelkleur}{Knoop\thesection:} 
\hspace{3pt}\textcolor{titelkleur}}
                   [\color{titelkleur}\titlerule]%\vspace{-3ex}\color{titelkleur}\rule{.5\columnwidth}{2pt}]
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}
\rule{3.5cm}{12cm}
\caption{emptyfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\section{section with line crossing wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

but when a section title is next to a wrapfigure, the titlerule overlaps with the figure.
Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

One can put `\section` inside a minipage, but that causes two other problems.  First, the minipage will be treated as a single line of text, confusing wrapfigure into thinking it is only `\baselineskip` in height.  (That is still a problem any time you change font size or add extra space.)  This was fixed by adding lots of fake lines to compensate.

The second problem is that the effects of `\@afterheading` are lost.  The easy fix is to add `\noindent` to the next line of text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor,wrapfig,lipsum}
\definecolor{titelkleur}{HTML}{92D851}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{28}{32}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedright}%\underline
 {}
 {-0.5cm}
 {\textcolor{titelkleur}{Knoop\thesection:} 
\hspace{3pt}\textcolor{titelkleur}}
                   [\color{titelkleur}\titlerule]%\vspace{-3ex}\color{titelkleur}\rule{.5\columnwidth}{2pt}]

\newcommand{\wrapspacer}[1]% #1 = special text
{\ifhmode\par\fi\leavevmode\bgroup
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hrule height0pt
    #1\hrule height0pt
    \end{minipage}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
  \loop\ifdim\dimen0>\baselineskip
    \strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}\newline
    \advance\dimen0 by -\baselineskip
  \repeat
  \noindent\usebox0
  \hrule height0pt
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}
\rule{3.5cm}{12cm}
\caption{emptyfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\wrapspacer{\section{section with line crossing wrapfigure}}
\noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: One of the best suggestion

Answer (score 2):

This answer replaces `\titlerule` in the definition of the section header formatting with `\rule{\linewidth}`. Now the length of the rule is proportional to the linewidth.

To get the text to respect the placement of the `wrapfig` item, it is placed in an `adjustbox`. The `adjustbox` is defined with spacing before and after the box, `vspace=\parskip` and set in a `minipage` with a width equal to `\linewidth`. The end of the wrapfig is defined with a `strut{}`, otherwise the text wrapping ends too late (i.e. the space allowed for the image is too large.

I replaced `lipsum` with `blindtext` passages to set smaller chunks of text, which better illustrates the text wrapping around the figure.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor,wrapfig,adjustbox}
\definecolor{titelkleur}{HTML}{92D851}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\fontsize{28}{32}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedright}%\underline
 {}
 {-0.5cm}
 {\textcolor{titelkleur}{Knoop\thesection:} 
\hspace{3pt}\textcolor{titelkleur}}
%                   [\color{titelkleur}\titlerule]%\vspace{-3ex}\color{titelkleur}\rule{.5\columnwidth}{2pt}] 
                    [\color{titelkleur}\rule{\linewidth}{0.4mm}]    

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{adjustbox}{
        vspace=\parskip,
        minipage=[c]{1.0\linewidth}
    }
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\linewidth}
\centering \rule{3.5cm}{8cm} 
\caption{emptyfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\strut{}        % This defines the end of the wrapfigure. It is required to get the correct linewidth for the rule under the heading
\Blindtext[1][10]
\section{section with line crossing wrapfigure}
\Blindtext[1][10]
\end{adjustbox} % place \end{adjustbox} at an appropriate place to end wrapping
\Blindtext[1][10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: \rule is in hmode and takes a full \baselineskip.  \hrule is in vmode and only takes 2\lineskip plus the rule height.