# Align wrapfigure with section title

Tags: wrapfigure

I have a picture inside a wrapfigure that I wish to have alongside a section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo_picture.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

\section{Section title}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the picture only starts at the beginning of the paragraph, and I want its top to be at the top of the section's title:

[image]

How to achieve this? I only have found answers to have the picture alongside of the title, but not next to both the title and the paragraph.

Comment: You can use manual vspace commands and shift it up. Be sure to reduce height (of the wrapfigure) at the same time.

Comment: See:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?s=1|0.0000#390544

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example solution:

```
\setlength\intextsep{12pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{0in}
  ...
\end{wrapfigure}
\vspace{-15pt} \leavevmode\section{Section title}
```

Here, `\leavevmode` overwrites the default effect of `\section`, which does not work with wrapfigure nicely.  But `\leavevmode` effectively creates a box with some space above the title.  The wrapfigure start position is anchored at the start of the box.  To counter it, `\vspace{-15pt}` is to move up the box position by 15pt, while `\setlength\intextsep{12pt}` is to move down the figure relative to the box position by 12pt.  Tweak these numbers to see their effects and adjust them if necessary.