# How to align section heading after wrapping text around figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, wrapfigure

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{texMemo}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\memoto{Anna C. Kelley, CEO and the BACH Creative Board of Directors}
\memofrom{Tanner N. Borskey, Project Developer}
\memosubject{Definition Memo: Defining What Solar Powered Traffic Signs Are and What They Are Used For}
\memodate{Thursday, January 10, 2019}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{bach.jpg}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

The purpose of this memo is to define "Solar Powered Traffic Signs" so that BACH Creative will understand why solar powered traffic signs are needed, how solar powered traffic lights work, and the different types of solar powered traffic signs available.

\color{cyan}
\section*{Why Solar Powered Traffic Signs Are Needed?}
\subsection*{Traditional Traffic Signs}
\color{black}
Traffic signs can be seen at pedestrian crosswalks, railroad crossings, speed warnings, school zone warnings, etc. Standard traffic signs in urban areas have illumination from surrounding light sources such traffic lights, security lights on buildings, and vehicle headlights. Compared to urban areas, rural area traffic signs often only are illuminated by driver headlights which is not sufficient. Unfortunately these traffic signs are currently the most common style of traffic signs still seen today. They are dependent on surrounding area light sources for illumination, outdated, and often ignored which ultimately increases the dangers of the road.

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{stat1.png}
\caption{Fatal Crashes by Traffic Control Devices [1]}
\end{wrapfigure}

\color{cyan}
\subsection*{Solar Powered Traffic Signs}

\color{black}
Solar powered traffic signs are the most up to date solution to increase traffic safety. These redesigned traffic signs prove to allow more visibility no matter of location or area. The number of fatal crashes just involving a STOP sign are the second leading result in fatal crashes in both 1999 and 2000 as seen in Figue 1. The inability to see a STOP sign due to lack of illumination are one of the leading reasons why these fatal crashes occur. Solar powered traffic signs would help eliminate a great percentage of fatalities by providing drivers with a bright, continuous flashing signal on the sign resulting in the sign becoming appearance becoming more visible to all drivers on the road. Inventor, David Hubbell states, "There is, therefore, a need to have an illuminated traffic sign that is visible to a driver before the vehicle's headlights hit it without depending on ambient lighting sources for illumination." \cite{bierman2006self}

\color{cyan}
\section*{How Do Solar Powered Traffic Signs Work?}

\color{black}
I NEED THIS SECTION HEADING AND TEXT TO ALIGN LEFT 


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you not just put the section heading before the wrapfig (also you should not have color in the document like that, just specify the colour at the same place that the section heading font is specified

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, please use a different document class and replace the pictures.

Comment: From a typographic view point, inputting a table as a figure is a bad idea, especially if you scale it such that the font sizes don't match. Best to reproduce this table in LaTeX code.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417299/wrapfig-package-question

Comment: The way you change your section headings is very wrong. You should not use `\color` there. Instead the definition of `\section` and the like should be changed to colour the headings. But that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following drops `wrapfig` and uses `insbox` instead (`insbox` is not a LaTeX2e package, but generic code, therefore it is `\input`). If you encounter stuff that shouldn't be affected anymore you can use `\insboxrestore` (which I just `\let` to an internal of `insbox`) to end `insbox`'s effect for the current and every following paragraphs. To get decent looking outputs with `\section` heading a bit of manual placement is needed (hence the `\vspace` macros) and the effect of the `\section` suppressing the resetting of the next paragraph's shape has to be suppressed (hence the `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair).

In order to get a `\caption` inside of `insbox`'s macro, one has to use a `\parbox` (or `minipage`) and the `capt-of` package's `\captionof` (also provided by the `caption` package and the KOMA script classes).

To change the margin around the inserted image and the surrounding text, you'd have to use something like

```
\makeatletter
\setlength\@InsertBoxMargin{<length>}% package default is 2mm
\makeatother
```

Note that in the following I use `article` as I don't have `texMemo` on my local machine and won't search for it. I also removed your `\color`s, as they are wrong in the way they are used, but can't provide a fix, because I don't know `texMemo`'s internal structure.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\insboxrestore}{\let\insboxrestore\@restore@}
\makeatother

%\memoto{Anna C. Kelley, CEO and the BACH Creative Board of Directors}
%\memofrom{Tanner N. Borskey, Project Developer}
%\memosubject{Definition Memo: Defining What Solar Powered Traffic Signs Are and What They Are Used For}
%\memodate{Thursday, January 10, 2019}
%\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{bach.jpg}}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle

The purpose of this memo is to define "Solar Powered Traffic Signs" so that BACH
Creative will understand why solar powered traffic signs are needed, how solar
powered traffic lights work, and the different types of solar powered traffic
signs available.

\section*{Why Solar Powered Traffic Signs Are Needed?}
\subsection*{Traditional Traffic Signs}
Traffic signs can be seen at pedestrian crosswalks, railroad crossings, speed
warnings, school zone warnings, etc. Standard traffic signs in urban areas have
illumination from surrounding light sources such traffic lights, security lights
on buildings, and vehicle headlights. Compared to urban areas, rural area
traffic signs often only are illuminated by driver headlights which is not
sufficient. Unfortunately these traffic signs are currently the most common
style of traffic signs still seen today. They are dependent on surrounding area
light sources for illumination, outdated, and often ignored which ultimately
increases the dangers of the road.
\vspace{-\baselineskip}% move the box a bit up
\InsertBoxL{0}
  {%
    \parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}
      {%
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}% move the image a bit down inside the box
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \captionof{figure}{Fatal Crashes by Traffic Control Devices [1]}
      }%
  }[13]% change this number if the number of short lines is wrong
% group the \subsection so that it doesn't interfere with \InsertBoxL. If you're
% not using `indentfirst` you'll have to suppress the indent in the first
% paragraph manually
\begingroup
\subsection*{Solar Powered Traffic Signs}
\endgroup

Solar powered traffic signs are the most up to date solution to increase traffic
safety. These redesigned traffic signs prove to allow more visibility no matter
of location or area. The number of fatal crashes just involving a STOP sign are
the second leading result in fatal crashes in both 1999 and 2000 as seen in
Figue 1. The inability to see a STOP sign due to lack of illumination are one of
the leading reasons why these fatal crashes occur. Solar powered traffic signs
would help eliminate a great percentage of fatalities by providing drivers with
a bright, continuous flashing signal on the sign resulting in the sign becoming
appearance becoming more visible to all drivers on the road. Inventor, David
Hubbell states, "There is, therefore, a need to have an illuminated traffic sign
that is visible to a driver before the vehicle's headlights hit it without
depending on ambient lighting sources for illumination." \cite{bierman2006self}

\section*{How Do Solar Powered Traffic Signs Work?}

I NEED THIS SECTION HEADING AND TEXT TO ALIGN LEFT 


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]