# How to wrap tikz diagrams around text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, alignment

I've tried using the wrapfig package, though this always results in my images going to the bottom-left corner. I have a document like this:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
lorem ipsum....
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (3.8,0) -- (3.8,0.5) -- (0,0); 
\node [below] at (1.9,0) {\(\sqrt{1450}\)}; \node [right] at (3.8,0.25) {\(5\)}; 
\node [below left] at (0,0) {\(A\)}; \node [above right] at (3.8,0.5) {\(B\)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It currently looks like [image: mwe] but I want it to look something like 
[image]

Comment: please provide complete but small document beginning by `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. from your code fragment is not seen that you try to use `wrapfigure`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Please also have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/121799).

Answer (score 3):

This works with no problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, wrapfig,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering\tikz\draw (0,0) --(0,12) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- cycle; 
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent\kant[1]\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (3.8,0) -- (3.8,0.5) -- (0,0); 
\node [below] at (1.9,0) {\(\sqrt{1450}\)}; \node [right] at (3.8,0.25) {\(5\)}; 
\node [below left] at (0,0) {\(A\)}; \node [above right] at (3.8,0.5) {\(B\)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that wrapfig treats the second tikzpicture as a singles line of text (\baselineskip).  See the \wrapspacer macro from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?s=1|13.9420#390544.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Or just properly use `cutwin` package :)