# Section environment inside a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, layout

How can I use the `\section` command inside a tikz node while the section counter is also preserved and so on. What comes to my mind is being able to use a tikz node like its a latex environment in which I can use all commands.
I was thinking about to use the standalone document type and import it into the node. Unfortunately this would results into the loss of the toc and moreover the section counter and much more.

It would be great to use tikz for the layout but preserving all the functionality from latex.

Comment: You can use `titlesec` to add whatever Ti*k*Z feature you want to add to the section. Having a `\section` in a node may not be that useful.

Comment: Keep in mind that \section contains \par, so a minipage or \parbox would be a good idea (width specified).  The [text width=...] option MIGHT be enough.  The counter will be saved globally.  You can also use a savebox (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?r=SearchResults&s=8|9.7909#390544).