# Issue with text wrapping around figures in LATEX

Tags: graphics, floats, wrapfigure, wrap

I am trying to write document (class article) with floating figures. I have found an issue with wrapping of text around some figures - The main text overlays part of the figure or caption. The figures are included to the document in wrapfigure environment, but the issue occurs also if I use floatingfigure environment.

Is there any way by which I could repair the text wrapping?

Thank you in advance.

Complete example. (It is quite long, but I haven't found any way how to shorten it more without disappearing of issue.) The issue occurs with second and last picture.:

```
% třída dokumentu
\documentclass[10pt,hidelinks]{article} %hidelinks odstraňuje rámečky kolem referencí.

% použité balíčky
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Zmenšení okrajů
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-9mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.9mm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{18mm}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-19mm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{19mm}

\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto,% or unicode
  psdextra,bookmarks
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={cnwun},
  pdftitle={YYYY: XXXXX}
}

% Číslování kapitol
\usepackage{secdot}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\title{XXXXXXXX}
\author{YYYYYY}
\date{ZS 2019}

%Obrázky a jejich obtékání
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{floatflt}


\begin{document}


Vazebná energie je
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon_j=\frac{\Delta mc^2}{A},
\end{equation*}
kde $\varepsilon_j$ je vazebná energie na jeden nukleon a $A$ je nukleonové číslo. V periodické tabulce bývá hmotnost celého atomu a je lepší odečíst hmotnost elektronu. To není zcela triviální kvůli relativistickým efektům. Existují tabulky, kde je hmotnost jader, podobně by tomu mělo být v testu. Největší vazebnou energii má železo.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{binding_energy.png}
    \caption{Vazebná energie na jeden nukleon pro různé prvky}
\end{wrapfigure}

Radioaktivita. Becquerel (?) objevil že všechny nuklidy těžší než bismut jsou přirozeně radioaktivní. $\alpha$ je proud jader helia. $\beta$ je proud elektronů (pozitronů). $\gamma$ je elektromagnetické záření.
\begin{align*}
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z-2}^{A-4} Y+\alpha \\
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z+1}^{A} Y+\beta \\
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z}^{A} Y+\gamma
\end{align*}

 Existují 4 různé rozpadové řady. To je kvůli tomu, že při $\alpha$ radioaktivitě se nukleonové číslo zmenšuje vždy oo 4. Celá situace se komplikuje Pauliho vylučovacím principem aplikovaným na spin částc.

 lorrefcverkjeb hvcrhbvrej bkvsjbjksv kdwjbfbpwoejcoikwnccioncowcnckl

\subsection*{Elektronový obal}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{quantum_skier.png}
    \caption{Kvantový lyžař setkavší se s překážkou}
\end{wrapfigure}



Existuje korpuskulárně vlnová dualita. Volný elektron může mít libovolnou (tj. nekavntovanou energii). Takový elektron se dá popsat pomocí své kinetické energie $E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ a hybnosti $p=mv$. Vlnová podstata elektronu se například může projevit při difrakci. Proto se zavádí de Broglieho vlna:
\begin{equation}
p=mv = \frac{h}{\lambda}
\end{equation}
Ve chvíli, kdy elektron spadne do potenciálové jámy atomového jádra začne být jeho energie kvantována. Planetární model nefunguje, protože kdyby se elektron pohyboval v magnetickém poli kolem jádra, tak by vyzařoval energii a spadl do jádra. Niels Bohr přišel na to, že elektrony mohou nabývat jen určitých energií.

Elektron je tedy jakási stojatá vlna. Jako taková může mít v sobě ukryty vyšší harmonické frekvence. Elektron se popisuje Schrödingerovou rovnicí:

\begin{align}
\hat{H}\psi_i=E_i \psi_i\\
\psi_i\longleftrightarrow E_i \nonumber
\end{align}
$\hat{H}$ je operátor pracující s vlnovou funkcí (něco jako druhá derivace) $\psi_i$ (někdy $\phi_i$). $i$ odpovídá různým harmonickým vlnám.


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.43\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.41\textwidth]{aufbau_principle.png}
    \caption{Výstavbový princip porovnává energie jednotlivých orbitalů.}
    \label{Hundt}
\end{wrapfigure}




Podle toho se třídí vazby. Kovalentní vazbu lze popsat molekulovými orbitaly. Iontovou vazbu stačí popisovat atomovými orbitaly, neboť si celý elektronový pár bere jede jeden z účastníků vazby. Při kovové vazbě elektrony tvoří elektronový plyn. Koordinačně kovalentní vazba je taková, ve které celý pár poskytuje pouze jeden partner.

Kromě těchto existují ještě různé slabé vazby, které nalézají uplatnění hlavně v mezimolekulárních interakcích. Vodíková vazba se realizuje mezi vodíkem a volným párem elktronů elektronegativního prvku.

29. 10. přednáška nebude.

\section{Reakční kinetika}

Pro reakci $aA+bB+cC\rightarrow dD$ je reakční rychlost definována jako:
\begin{equation}
v=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{d\left[ A\right]}{dt}
\end{equation}
Tato závisí na koncentraci reagentů:
\begin{equation}
v=k\cdot\left[A\right]^\alpha\left[B\right]^\beta\left[C\right]^\gamma
\label{rychl_konc}
\end{equation}

MEZERAMEZERAMEZERA


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.41\textwidth]{Arrhenius_Plot.png}
        \caption{Linearisace Arrheniovy rovnice podle rovnice \ref{Arr_lin}.}
        \label{Arr_lin_plot}
\end{wrapfigure}

Reakční rychlost také ovlivňuje teplota. Výzkumem jejího vlivu se zabýval Arrhenius. Teplota ovlivňuje $k$ v rovnici \ref{rychl_konc}. Arrhenius odvodil následující rovnici:
\begin{equation}
k=A\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}},
\end{equation}
kde $R$ je molární plynová konstanta, $E_A$ je aktivační energie (energie potřebná na rozrušení starých vazeb). Tato rovnice se dá linearizovat:
\begin{equation}
ln k = ln A-\frac{E_A}{RT}
\label{Arr_lin}
\end{equation}
Dá se to vynést do grafu $ln k \sim \frac{1}{T}$ (viz obrázek \ref{Arr_lin_plot}). Při nulové hodnotě $\frac{1}{T}$ lze odečíst hodnotu $lnA$.

Vysvětlení rovnice spočívá ve srážkové teorii. Lze popsat rozdělení energií srážek částic. Platí, že:
\begin{equation}
P\left( E>E_A\right) =e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}
Pro teoretickou velikost $k$ platí:
\begin{equation}
k=Z\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}
Často je $Z=A$, pokud je ale $A<Z$, tak jde obvykle o vliv sterických faktorů. Zavádí se proto sterický faktor $P \left( P<1\right) $ zohledňující pravděpodobnost správného natočení částic:
\begin{equation}
k=P\cdot Z\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}

Aktivační energie zjištěná experimentem je vždycky menší než ta odvozená ze srážkové teorie. Proto se zavádí teorie aktivovaného komplexu. Při vzniku nových vazeb se totiž část energie uvolní nazpět.

Kromě koncentrace a teploty rychlost konkrétní reakce ovlivňuje přítomnost katalyzátoru. Katalyzátor se reakce (př. $A+B\rightarrow AB$) zdálivě neúčastní:

\end{document}
```

Non-compilable examples below:

First example:

```
    kde $\varepsilon_j$ je vazebná energie na jeden nukleon a $A$ je nukleonové číslo. V periodické tabulce bývá hmotnost celého atomu a je lepší odečíst hmotnost elektronu. To není zcela triviální kvůli relativistickým efektům. Existují tabulky, kde je hmotnost jader, podobně by tomu mělo být v testu. Největší vazebnou energii má železo.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{binding_energy.png}
    \caption{Vazebná energie na jeden nukleon pro různé prvky}
\end{wrapfigure}

Radioaktivita. Becquerel (?) objevil že všechny nuklidy těžší než bismut jsou přirozeně radioaktivní. $\alpha$ je proud jader helia. $\beta$ je proud elektronů (pozitronů). $\gamma$ je elektromagnetické záření.
\begin{align*}
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z-2}^{A-4} Y+\alpha \\
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z+1}^{A} Y+\beta \\
{}_{Z}^{A} X \rightarrow {}_{Z}^{A} Y+\gamma
\end{align*}

 Existují 4 různé rozpadové řady. To je kvůli tomu, že při $\alpha$ radioaktivitě se nukleonové číslo zmenšuje vždy oo 4. Celá situace se komplikuje Pauliho vylučovacím principem aplikovaným na spin částc.

\subsection*{Elektronový obal}

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{quantum_skier.png}
    \caption{Kvantový lyžař setkavší se s překážkou}
\end{floatingfigure}



Existuje korpuskulárně vlnová dualita. Volný elektron může mít libovolnou (tj. nekavntovanou energii). Takový elektron se dá popsat pomocí své kinetické energie $E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ a hybnosti $p=mv$. Vlnová podstata elektronu se například může projevit při difrakci. Proto se zavádí de Broglieho vlna:
\begin{equation}
p=mv = \frac{h}{\lambda}
\end{equation}
Ve chvíli, kdy elektron spadne do potenciálové jámy atomového jádra začne být jeho energie kvantována. Planetární model nefunguje, protože kdyby se elektron pohyboval v magnetickém poli kolem jádra, tak by vyzařoval energii a spadl do jádra. Niels Bohr přišel na to, že elektrony mohou nabývat jen určitých energií.

Elektron je tedy jakási stojatá vlna. Jako taková může mít v sobě ukryty vyšší harmonické frekvence. Elektron se popisuje Schrödingerovou rovnicí:

\begin{align}
\hat{H}\psi_i=E_i \psi_i\\
\psi_i\longleftrightarrow E_i \nonumber
\end{align}
$\hat{H}$ je operátor pracující s vlnovou funkcí (něco jako druhá derivace) $\psi_i$ (někdy $\phi_i$). $i$ odpovídá různým harmonickým vlnám.
```

[image: First example]

Second example:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.41\textwidth]{Arrhenius_Plot.png}
        \caption{Linearisace Arrheniovy rovnice podle rovnice \ref{Arr_lin}.}
        \label{Arr_lin_plot}
\end{wrapfigure}

Reakční rychlost také ovlivňuje teplota. Výzkumem jejího vlivu se zabýval Arrhenius. Teplota ovlivňuje $k$ v rovnici \ref{rychl_konc}. Arrhenius odvodil následující rovnici:
\begin{equation}
k=A\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}},
\end{equation}
kde $R$ je molární plynová konstanta, $E_A$ je aktivační energie (energie potřebná na rozrušení starých vazeb). Tato rovnice se dá linearizovat:
\begin{equation}
ln k = ln A-\frac{E_A}{RT}
\label{Arr_lin}
\end{equation}
Dá se to vynést do grafu $ln k \sim \frac{1}{T}$ (viz obrázek \ref{Arr_lin_plot}). Při nulové hodnotě $\frac{1}{T}$ lze odečíst hodnotu $lnA$.

Vysvětlení rovnice spočívá ve srážkové teorii. Lze popsat rozdělení energií srážek částic. Platí, že:
\begin{equation}
P\left( E>E_A\right) =e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}
Pro teoretickou velikost $k$ platí:
\begin{equation}
k=Z\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}
Často je $Z=A$, pokud je ale $A<Z$, tak jde obvykle o vliv sterických faktorů. Zavádí se proto sterický faktor $P \left( P<1\right) $ zohledňující pravděpodobnost správného natočení částic:
\begin{equation}
k=P\cdot Z\cdot e^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}.
\end{equation}

Aktivační energie zjištěná experimentem je vždycky menší než ta odvozená ze srážkové teorie. Proto se zavádí teorie aktivovaného komplexu. Při vzniku nových vazeb se totiž část energie uvolní nazpět.
```

[image: Second example]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I will prepare complete code.  Maybe it will be necessary to upload full text because the issue doesn't occur with every figure.

Comment: In fact, the process of reducing the code to obtain a minimal example that cannot further be reduced (because then either the problem vanishes or it doesn't compile anymore) is very important in identifying what could be the problem. It is probably enough to show an example with just one figure that doesn't work (or maybe with each one `wrapfigure` and `floatingfigure`, to be able to see the differences).

Comment: note that `wrapfigure` has an optional argument to say how many lines should be shortened to make room so you can use that to leave more space `floatingfigure` is not an enviornment I recognise and you have given no clue to the definition so I can not comment on that.

Comment: Wrapfig assumes that every line takes up \baselineskip.  The  align environment is treated as one line of text.  One solution is to use the \wrapspacer macro from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.0319#390544

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. The solutions with optional argument and \wrapspacer macro work. It is just necessary to set correctly the number of lines or place the macro correctly.

Comment: Unrelated to problem: A blank line shouldn't be present before a math display; it will foul up the vertical spacing and allow a page break there.  (And since a display is logically considered a continuation of the paragraph, it should continue directly.)

Comment: So far, I have never used wrapfigure or floatingfigure , instead I would have used minipage and embed text and floats with that. 


\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
% insert text 
\end{minipage}
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
% insert figure 
\end{minipage}


But, the number of lines is not taken into account, and you should manage vertical spacing with \vspace .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easy to use:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{r}{0.45\textwidth} 
% 22 is the number of lines you want this environment to be

% insert all the figures
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: When counting lines, equations count as 3. Other things that need handling are section titles and the vertical spacing in lists. That looks like the problem for one of them, but the sample with two figures consecutive looks like the wrapping got lost for the second one. Check the log file for warnings, and beware of paragraphs that start in a local group. DO NOT expect wrapfigure and floatfigure to cooperate!