# How to remove additional space under wrapfigure when using vspace in text

Tags: formatting, environments, paragraphs, wrapfigure, vspace

I'm creating some custom environments. One of them will be placed in `\wrapfigure` and second one will contain text which should wrap around the first one.

When I'm adding `\vspace` between paragraphs, blank space under `\wrapfiture` environment gets higher.

Is there any way of removing this blank space?

I can't specify exact number of lines that `\wrapfigure` will take, because it can vary.I would like to be able to configure space between parahraphs in my second environment.

Below I prepared MWE of text without `\vspace` and with `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.29\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[1]\\

    \blindtext[1]\\

    \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.29\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[1]\\
    \vspace{50pt}
    \blindtext[1]\\
    \vspace{50pt}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I developed a \wrapspacer macro (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.0368#390544) for this problem (more or less).  The usual approach is to manually tell wrapfigure how many lines of text to wrap.

Comment: `\blindtext[1]\\ ` is simply wrong, never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph it generates warnings and makes very poor output. Or here you are not ending the paragraph at all, but simply inserting space between lines of the same pararaph.

Answer (score 1):

Your example text, outside the wrapfig only had a single paragraph, with vertical space inserted between the lines. That is hard to catch (and using vspace mid-paragraph has slightly strange effects,  it is almost always better to finish the paragraph with a blank line before adding space.

Here I locally set the paragraph spacing to 50pt, and adjust  `wrapfig` so that each paragraph end counts as an additional 4 lines (actually 5 lines gets better spacing here but 5*12 being 60 > 50 would mean  actually you are over compensating and could result in not enough space being left. 12pt being the default baseline space here.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength\parskip{50pt}
\def\WF@mypar{\relax
 \WF@@par % what the rest of LaTeX expects \par to be (usually \@@par)
 \ifnum\@@parshape=\z@ \let\WF@pspars\@empty \fi % reset `parshape'
 \global\advance\c@WF@wrappedlines-\prevgraf \prevgraf\z@
 \global\advance\c@WF@wrappedlines-4
 \ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines<\tw@ \WF@finale \fi}


    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.29\linewidth}

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
            \item Test item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[1]

    \blindtext[1]


    \blindtext[1]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]