# Space below wrapfigure

Tags: graphics, positioning, wrapfigure

I tried to use `wrapfigure`, and I had some problems.

After compiling I got

[image]

The text of this picture was:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{reactdvig.png}
    \caption{\label{fig:frog1}This is a figure caption.}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I disliked at all these blank spaces, so I googled and I found that I need to put `~\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after `\end{wrapfigure}`. Unfortunately, I got

[image]

So nothing is good, I have formulas on place, which is devoted to space between picture and caption.

How can I make it working properly?
Why I have such problems? Is wrapfigure so undeveloped, or I just don't know how to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide MWE (minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. `wrapfigure` does not work well across multiple paragraphs.

Comment: I should mention \wrapspacer for completeness (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390520/have-titlerule-not-overlap-wrapfigure/390544?s=5%7C0.0000#390544) although manually setting the number of lines is easier.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a stupid question, I forgot that there should be a parameter `[14]`, so code should like:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{reactdvig.png}
    \caption{примерный вид реактивного сопла}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Not dumb. The line count is optional, but is often needed when there is extra spacing in the text.... more comment would be long, so will answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the critical input text, but it appears you have blank lines (`\par`) around your equations:

```
text text text

\begin{equation}
math math math
\end{equation}

because more text text
```

That is wrong! It is giving you indented paragraphs on the lines between equations when you are in the middle of a sentence. It may also lead to poor page breaks (having a page start with an equation). It also hurts the operation of wrapfig in two ways:

1. As you found early on, when the wrapping paragraph begins inside an equation environment (or other local group) the wrapping may get stuck "on". If you eliminate the blank lines you won't need the hack of `~\vspace{-\baselineskip}` (which functions to start the paragraph with a hidden line of no-text).
2. LaTeX also does something like `~\vspace{-\baselineskip}` internally when you put an equation at the beginning of a paragraph (still within the equation local group) which counts as a line and so messes up the line count for wrapping. For 3 equations in the wrapped segments, it would give a miscount of 3. Since a value of 14 looks right, my guess is that wrapfig *should* have chosen 11, which came out too short.

So use

```
text text text
%
\begin{equation}
math math math
\end{equation}
%
because more text text
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I didn't know that there should be `%`.